# SELECT in cake php

Tags: cakephp, select

In this form I can't see name of select, this dropdown don't work, my code is:

In the controller I have:

```
public function admin_cambiar_centro() {
      $this->Session->write(
          'Auth.User.centro_id', 
          $this->request->data('CambioCentro.centro_id')
      );
      $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

In the view:

```
<?= $this->Form->create('CambioCentro', array(
    'url' => array(
        'controller'=> 'Users', 
        'action' => 'cambiar_centro'
     )
)) ?>
<?= $this->Form->select('centro_id', 
    Hash::combine(AuthComponent::User('Centro'), '{n}.id', '{n}.nombre'), 
    array(
        'empty' => false,
        'value' => AuthComponent::User('centro_id'),
        'style' => 'margin-top: 7px;',
        'onchange' => 'this.form.submit()',
 )); ?>
 <?=$this->Form->end()?>
```

and this does not deploy I would be very grateful if you could help me

Comment: What does the HTML generated by your code look like? (Not the whole page, just the <form>..</form> bit)

Comment: does not display list, does not display any options

Comment: What I meant is: when you choose the 'View Page Source' option in your browser what is the actual HTML code where the the <select> element should be? If there is anything you could paste it into your question.

Comment: <select name="data[CambioCentro][centro_id]" style="margin-top: 7px;" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="CambioCentroCentroId">
</select>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form url is not correct. Try to add admin => true to the form's url.

```
<?=$this->Form->create('CambioCentro', array('url' => 
             array('controller' 
             => 'Users', 'action' => 'cambiar_centro', 'admin' => true)))?>
```

Another potential problem is that you are writing to the session and redirecting on every request, so you may create a redirect loop, and also on get request the session variable gets overwritten.

Check the request type in the action:

```
public function admin_cambiar_centro() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Session->write('Auth.User.centro_id', 
            $this->request->data('CambioCentro.centro_id'));
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I see This Argument 1 passed to Hash::combine() must be of the type array, null given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cakephp-2.10.3/app/View/Layouts/admin.ctp on line 90 and defined [CORE/Cake/Utility/Hash.php, line 390]